# how to perform some action on span element of div?

Tags: jquery

I need help in selecting the span element within div so that i can perform action on click of these buttons (delete,rename,move). These buttons will come when i hover on any file. Many thanks in advance for help.

[image]

Comment: [Show actual code...not images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1175966)

Comment: Have you already read the api documentation of jquery?

Comment: @charlietfl actually the code was written in jquery to render the options-panel so it was long so avoided

Comment: @reporter no i havent read i am a newbie in jQuery

Comment: html can be copied right from browser dev tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){ // equivalent to document on ready state
    $("body").on("click", "#delete", function(){
        //code goes here
    });
});
```

This should do the trick, and of course to handle all the `spans` you can replace the `"#delete"` with the id's of the other spans. Hope this helps!

Comment: @NikhilJaitak if you could mark this as Accepted Answer, for future visitors to solve their issue faster! thanks!

Comment: 2 times it is iterating to show two alerts can you please help in it?

Comment: @NikhilJaitak provide me with a jsFiddle and I will take a look. Something tells me that you have 2 `$(function(){ //code here })` and thats why it is showing twice. If you provide me your code I will take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Solution


By using jQuery you can do like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hiding  first
  $('.parent_b').hide();
  //Hovering Second
  $('.sep_div').hover(function(){
    $('.parent_b').show();
  },
  function(){
    $('.parent_b').hide();
  });

});
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/ep0xu3s5/